# After iScroll initialization in mobile web app ... textbox is not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making mobile web app in Html, css, javascript, jquery . 
I am initializing iScroll on page .
iScroll is working fine .
Page contains textbox . It becomes not editable after iScroll intialization. 
even z-index isn't useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, There is alternative ....
https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll

download example and put your text box and just try ...
My edited example is here http://www.mediafire.com/?uzb5wa0m5hd3dgq

Touch to scroll and you can edit text also ....

Answer (score 1):

I have made my text box working in an iscroll enabled div

Just below the form elements add this javascript

```
var selectField = document.getElementById('input_field');
selectField.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

This works for me in iphone 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dom element listening to events like `ontouchstart`, the event first triggers on the element and then ultimately bubbles up to the DOM, where the browser picks it up and does it's browser related work - scrolling, checkboxes, etc.

On the other hand, iScroll prevents this event from bubbling up. The reason iScroll does this is to prevent the browser's default scrolling from kicking in.

The short answer: It's not possible to put a textbox inside iScroll.

Comment: It is reported bug..http://code.google.com/p/iscroll-js/issues/detail?id=17 .... But is there any solution to this .... As I want Scroller and textbox in page

Comment: Yup, I just read about it today: http://fioravengi.blogspot.in/2011/06/implications-of-ios-5-webkit-overflow.html

There are still some issues, but am sure that there'll be some nice functionality for overflow scrolling added over the next few months.